# How to Download telegram animated stickers with telethon

Tags: telethon

I've downloaded an animated sticker with `client.download_media(sticker_document, "any_stciker.webp")`. The `client` is **telethon** bot client; for instance `client = TelegramClient('', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=token)`. But downloaded stickers are corrupted and I can't open them. I've downloaded normal stickers(not animated) through this method and they are ok.

Comment: animated stickers are .json files not webp and you can't open them with a normal image viewer

Comment: Do you know any tool to convert .tgs to .webp?

Comment: I found this python library https://pypi.org/project/lottie/

Comment: yes that one should work.